# What's wrong with Razor markup?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to learn MVC and using samples from the "Pro ASP .net MVC 2". Only I'm trying to write everything in MVC3.

first I had some problem with  @Html.RenderAction thing, I changed it to @Html.Action - it did the trick. 
Now I have a problem. Could you tell me why ascx view works and similar Razor doesn't?

ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<SportsStore.WebUI.Models.NavLink>>" %>

<% foreach (var link in Model) { %>
<%: Html.RouteLink(link.Text, link.RouteValues, new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "class", link.IsSelected ? "selected" : null }
}) %>
<% } %>
```

Razor:

```
@model IEnumerable<SportsStore.WebUI.Models.NavLink>
@foreach (var link in Model)
{
   Html.RouteLink(link.Text, link.RouteValues, new Dictionary<string, object> { {    "class", link.IsSelected ? "selected" : null } });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Html.RouteLink` method returns an `IHtmlString`.
It does not write anything to the page.

You need to write the returned `IHtmlString` to the page by writing `@Html.RouteLink(...)`.
This is Razor's equivalent to the `<%: Html.RouteLink(...) %>` in the ASCX page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@model IEnumerable<SportsStore.WebUI.Models.NavLink>
@foreach (var link in Model)
{
   @Html.RouteLink(link.Text, link.RouteValues, new { @class = link.IsSelected ? "selected" : string.empty });
}
```